# How Blender 2.49 subdivide edges work to implement in 2.78

Tags: mesh

Hi I need known how  blender 2.49 subdivide edges algorithm work to replicate on blender 2.78. I need for export mesh to another software but 2.78 mode dont work for me , I try with all type of subdivision and any work for me. Thanks in advance. Regards

Comment: please try to explain more clearly (and maybe with an example image, or a .blend file) what you mean by "subdivide edges", and also which is the software where you need to import. There is no way to replicate 2.49 behaviour, unless modify Blender 2.78 itself, but there could be another way to do what you need...

Comment: I need export mesh to panda3d for generate a collision mesh for pathfinding I don't have problem if I have to modificate blender sources. I work with my own build. The problem is how blender subdivide edges work any option don't work for me ecept when make plane on 2.49 and subdivide edges on edit mode I need known how blender make this programaticaly I Inspect the source code of blender 2.49 and I have not been able to find it.

Comment: ok but you are still say very little about your workflow. I know nothing about 249 vs 278 internals, but you need to export meshes, not methods, into panda3d, I think. I found this page https://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Converting_from_Blender, are you using which method, and what happens with 249, and what with 278?